# How to get the JSON property value or the key in Angular template? to render the JSON value?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

My problem is that I'm unable to render `JSON` values of some properties on screen.

I'm using **Angular Material** table to render my JSON response.

*below code to render the JSON on screen*

```
 <mat-card-content class="dashboard-card-content">
    <div></div>
    <div *ngIf="card.title===title1" class="custom-table-container mat-elevation-z8">
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSourceGeneralShift" class="">

        <!-- Name Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="Name">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let col" class="align-left"> {{col.Name}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <!-- day10 Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="day10">
          <th class="table-header" mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Shift </th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let col" class="align-left" > {{col | json}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"> </tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"> </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
 </mat-card-content>
```

*In **day10** column I used `{{col | json}}` this is to just check whether I'm getting the data from the API or not!*

My requirement is to render the Month values from **day1** to **day31**

the `JSON` return value contains day1 on 1st of every month,
day2 on 2nd of every month and so on.
Every 'day-' property value contains different values, Ex: 'Shift 1', 'Shift 2' etc.

Every `JSON` response is different.
EX:

**day15 response**

```
[
 {
   "Name": "Bravo",
   "day15": "Shift 1"
 }
]
```

**day20 response**

```
[
 {
   "Name": "Adam",
   "day20": "Shift 2"
 }
]
```

** Problem:**
Because of changing *key* values (day1, day2, ..., day31) how to render it on the Angular Material table template?

Comment: IMO this is a data/metadata design flaw. You are using the **value** for day as the **key** for shift. Your response data should be formatted the same way regardless of the request parameters: { "Name": "xxxxx", "Day": "yyyyy", "Shift": "zzzzz" }. Keys should not be used to indicated request parameter data or any other data values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically just use `Object.keys` static method to get array of keys present in response object. If you are sure, that there are always two entries, just pick one that is not `Name`:

```
public getDayVal(data){
  Object.keys(data).forEach((k) => {
    if (k !== 'Name') return data[k];
  })
}
```

If you are not sure, then just `Regex` key to detect is it matching:

```
public getDayVal(data){
  let re = /^day[0-9]+$/;
  Object.keys(data).forEach((k) => {
    if (re.test(k)) return data[k];
  })
}
```

then in template use above helper function to extract varying key:

```
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let col" class="align-left" > {{getDayVal(col)}} </td>
```

**Important**
I'm skipping all additional but in your case necessary sanity checks like verifying will the helper method finally return anything and what shall happen if desired `dayXX` key is not found. It's up to you to deal with this, now table will just not render nothing in column due to `undefined` returned form helper.

And most important: change your data model if you are in charge of it. Encoding information in *field* is just basic design flaw. Something like:

```
interface DayIfc {
  Name: string;
  Day: number;
  Shift: number;
}
```

Would resolve all your issues.

Comment: Glad I was able to help